# How to read and write xlxs and csv file using nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, node-modules

first, I want to upload .xlxs and .csv file in node.js. then I want to read this file, edit this file, and also want to save this file in mongoose schema in the database.
and I am new in node.js and I want to learn node backend
please guide me, how I can do this and is this possible?

Comment: please remember to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing files in `node` uses the `fs` module. Its already included in core node so simply include it

```js
const fs = require('fs')

// synchronous version that will wait until the whole file is read
let file_data = fs.readFileSync('/file/path/file.csv' , 'utf-8') 

// async version
fs.readFile('/file/path/file.csv' , 'utf-8', (err, file_data) => {

 if (err)
   console.error(err)
else
   console.info(file_data)
   // file_data is your data as string

})
```

If you specifically need to read and edit `csv`/`xlsx` you'll need to browse `NPM` for packages that help out with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using [sheetjs](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs)

See this example : https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/tree/master/demos/server